# Chebyshev Polynomials and the Hypergeometric Function

Tags: special-functions

A problem related to Chebyshev Polynomials and the Hypergeometric Function involves transformation from one function to another. The task is to transform the Chebyshev polynomial into its correct scaled Hypergeometric Function. $$
T_{2n} (x) = ( - 1)^n {}_2F_1 \left( { - n,n;\tfrac{1}{2};x^2 } \right).
$$
Is there any way for me to make use of the relationship below?
$$
T_n (x) = {}_2F_1 \left( { - n,n;\tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{{1 - x}}{2}} \right).
$$

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: It seems that relating T_n(x) and T_2n(x) can't be done using elementary algebra and any form of recursion. Any hints in arriving the answer given above?

Comment: @Qmechanic I just love how physicists arrive at a simple and hand-waving solutions. But okay, I will be posting this on mathematics field for contrast too.

Comment: Exact copy of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067996/chebyshev-polynomials-and-the-hypergeometric-function You may try showing that the hypergeometric function you are given and $T_{2n}(x)$ both satisfy the same ODE with certain initial values, and conclude that they must be equal.

Comment: Perhaps another way would be to start with the differential equation for $ {}_2F_1 \left( { - n,n;\tfrac{1}{2};z } \right)$, then derive from that the differential equation for $( - 1)^n {}_2F_1 \left( { - n,n;\tfrac{1}{2};x^2 } \right)$, and compare to the differential equation for $T_{2n}(x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Does it mean that the starting equation should be the differential equation itself?

Answer (score 2):

The Chebyshev polynomials are defined by
$$
T_n(\cos\theta)=\cos(n\theta).
$$
Hence
$$
T_{2n}(\cos(\theta))=\cos(2n\theta)=T_n(\cos(2\theta)).
$$
We now use the relation $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos(\theta)^2-1$ and write $\cos\theta=x$ to get
$$
T_{2n}(x)=T_n(2x^2-1).
$$
This should prove the claimed relation.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I was able to obtain the equivalent hypergeometric function!

Answer (score 2):

Let me carry out my suggestion.
Start [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation) with the differential equation for ${}_2F_1$:
The solution of
$$
z(1-z)F''(z)+\left(\frac12 - z\right)F'(z)+n^2 F(z) = 0,\quad F(0)=1, F'(0)=-2n^2
\tag1$$
is
$$
F(z) = {}_2F_1\left(-n,n;\frac12;z\right) .
$$
Change variables $z=x^2$.  Then we have:  The solution of
$$
(1-x^2)F''(x)-xF'(x)+4n^2F(x) = 0,\quad F(0)=1,F'(0)=0
\tag2$$
is
$$
F(x) = {}_2F_1\left(-n,n;\frac12;x^2\right) .
$$

Next, [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_equation) we find that the Chebyshev polynomial $T_m(x)$ satisfies
$$
(1-x^2)T_m''(x)-xT_m'(x)+m^2T_m(x)=0
\tag3$$
Put $m=2n$, then $(3)$ becomes $(2)$.  Also $T_{2n}(0)=(-1)^{n}, T_{2n}'(0)=0$.
Therefore
$$
T_{2n}(x) = (-1)^n\;{}_2F_1\left(-n,n;\frac12;x^2\right) .
$$

Comment: Okay, I got the basic idea here. This is way too beautiful!